# Magento1.9: Modify payment_html variable

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, third-party-module

I  use an extension called [FireGento GermanSetup](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-germansetup) which adds variables like IBAN and SWIFT etc. I changed the SWIFT variable to BIC and now I would like to show BIC in the payment infos which are used in every transaction email and PDFs.

I changed the SWIFT label to BIC here:

```
/app/code/community/FireGento/GermanSetup/etc/system.xml
```

The field in the backend in now labeled with BIC which is good but it doesn't seem to work for transaction emails.

When I open a Transaction email preview in the backend. It still shows SWIFT instead of BIC.

Comment: could you please add your screenshot? you want to change only label?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes only the label, the field in the backend in now properly labeled BIC but the transaction email still show SWIFT

Comment: FireGento GermanSetup is outdated, please use FireGento MageSetup: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup

Comment: Which localization are you using? (for ex en_Us or different?)

Comment: I used de_DE. I modified the local file (.csv) as suggested below and it worked

Comment: Good to know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how Firegento works, but I can recommend 2 ways to change the label.

First try to change it in your translation file (depending on locale), for example `en_US`, insert:

```
"SWIFT","BIC"
```

If Firegento made the label translatable, this will work.

If that doesn't work, I would recommend downloading the entire Firegento module and do a text search for `SWIFT` (you'll have to use a program which does this - if you don't have one, with a quick Google search you'll find many free programs that do this).

You will then have to go through all the files where SWIFT is found and try to deduce which one you have to change.

Comment: I edited the question. I tried modified the /app/design/adminhtml/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml file but for some reason the changes are not showing when I open a transaction email preview in the backend. I did edit the translation inside: /app/code/community/FireGento/GermanSetup/etc/system.xml but the label is only updated in the backend, not in the transaction email preview

Comment: Try the 1st two recommendations. I'll remove that part from my answer as well.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!